# Error setting Database Initializer: Type argument 'Configuration' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'DbContext'

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first

I'm applying Code-First to an existing database in MS SQL Server 2012. I've done: right-click project -> add item -> ADO.net Entity Data Model -> Code-First from database. By this, all tables from the database is imported into my web API project.

Then, following [this](http://devgush.com/2014/02/24/migrating-a-project-from-database-first-to-code-first/#comment-13535) blog post, i've skipped steps 1 & 2 and proceeded to step 3 successfully. Then at step 4, since i'm doing a new project, not migrating a project from Database-First; instead of creating a new class to Set Database Initializer, somebody suggested that i put this snippet inside the constructor of my DbContext class:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Migrations.Configuration, WorkflowDbContext>());
```

This is after i implemented given code into my DbContext class:

```
Partial Public Class DbContext1
    Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=DbContext1")
    Database.SetInitializer(New MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of Migrations.Configuration, DbContext1))
End Sub
```

But when i do this, errors at the keywords in my code above, i summarised below:

> - SetInitializer: "Type argument 'Configuration' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'DbContext'. "
> - Migrations.Configuration: "Type argument 'Configuration' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'DbContext'. "
> - DbContext1: "Type argument 'DbContext1' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'DbMigrationsConfiguration(Of Configuration)'. "

Right now, i'm modifying(adding foreign keys and navigation properties) the model classes that were automatically imported from the database using EF-code-first. Is this the cause to the problem i'm facing now?

Could someone point out to me what i should do to mend the problems?

P/S:

1. I have only one DbContext and one Configuration in my project.
2. Since the code above didn't work yet, i purposely skipped steps 4 for the sake of trying. I also skipped step 5 because my ConnectionString is already of type DbContext. So i proceeded to step 6. Surprisingly, it worked! I did Add-Migration initial, and now an 'initial' class has been created. But i'm quite worried if skipping those steps will cause an effect later on. Does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of Migrations.Configuration, DbContext1)) to  MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of DbContext1,Migrations.Configuration)) 
I think you reversed the order of type argumen

Comment: I re-scaffold the migration 'initial' by re-entering Add-Migration initial, then it said "Only the Designer Code for migration 'initial' was re-scaffolded. To re-scaffold the entire migration, use the -Force parameter." For my case, do i need to re-scaffold the entire migration or not?